# Detect UserControl in Toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a UserControl Library with several controls. I can choose this control from the toolbox in a WPF Project in Visual Studio 2012.
Is there a way to detect which UserControl is selected in the Toolbox?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that.  Could you explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Forget the "Toolbox", WPF is not winforms. nobody cares about the Visual Studio designer in WPF.

Comment: I know that nobody cares about VS designer but for business reason I have to do it. I designed a User Control that allows to draw Lines at design time like in Blend and now I need a way to know what user Control is the one active. Please reply if you have any idea on How to do this (Maybe with the EnvDTE object?) and not on Why to do this. Thank you.